# Get EOFError When Performing x = input ("input x:" ) in Python 3

Tags: python, input, eoferror

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77DE4.jpg)

```
try:
    x= ""
    x = input("input x: ")
    print  (x)
except EOFError as e:
    print  (x)
    print  ("end")
```

Running this code in Python 3 produces the following output:

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6uTAV.jpg)

The two lines of output are from the `EOFError` handler.
It looks like the input() function is reading the prompt as data. Please help.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this behaviour, which version of python are you using?

Comment: Likewise, I can't reproduce this (Python 3.6.5)

Answer (score 0):

you are printing **x** in the exception, you should be printing **e**

```
    try:
    x= ""
    x = input("input x: ")
    print  (x)

except EOFError as e:
    print  (e)
    print  ("end")
```